# Tutorial for c# and ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, c#, references

I am new to the ArcGIS.

Can any one please refer a beginners tutorial for this tool.

Referred the help, but couldn't able to get the basics to kick start.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include a link to the part of the help that you are stuck on, please?

Answer (score 4):

If you already have some programming background then after you install Visual Studio (check ESRI documentation for the correct version of VS and .Net framework as latest version are NOT supported.) completing the **[Building Add-Ins with ArcGIS Decktop walk-trough](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/)** is a good start.  After you successfully complete this, you can start building simple add-ins by using the official code snippets that get installed with the SDK to become more familiar with ArcObjects.

For VB.Net the snippets are installed in: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VBExpress\Snippets\ArcObjects"